# Adding v-lines to plot in base R using time series object

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to add vertical lines to a time series plot I made in base R `plot(data1,type = 'l',lwd = 1.5, family = "A", ylab ="", xlab = "", main = "")`. This plot has a total of 5 plots inside of it. There are two x-axes that are the same[image] (see current plot)

When adding vlines with `abline(v=c(27,87, 167, 220, 280, 329), lty=2)` I get this result [image]

Is there a way to get them to go on the graphs so it looks something like this but with dashed lines and the lines within the plots.
Or if you know of a better way to plot this in ggplot that would be fantastic as well. Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a toy example of using ggplot to put in vlines.

```
library(tidyverse)


iris2 <- iris %>% pivot_longer(cols=Sepal.Length:Petal.Length)


ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales="free_y", ncol=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(.25, .75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25), 
             linetype='dashed', col = 'blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`plot`  calls `plot.ts`. This has a `panel=` argument in which you may define a function what should happen in the panels. Since you want a `grid` and the usual `lines`, you can do quite easily:

```
panel <- function(...) {grid(col=1, ny=NA, lty=1); lines(...)}
plot(z, panel=panel)
```

[image]

`grid` usually uses the `axTicks` and you can define number of cells, see `?grid`.

This also works with `abline`.

```
panel <- function(...) {abline(v=seq(1961, 1969, 2), col=1,lty=1); lines(...)}
plot(z, panel=panel)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 5), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
```